# How to set timestamp to spreadsheet using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

i need help here.
I want to get a timestamp in the spreadsheet everytime i submit a row.  i try so many ways, but it failed. can anyone help me? these are my GoogleApp Script :

```
function doGet(e) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Spreadsheet link");
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

   addUser(e, sheet);
}

function doPost(e) {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Spreadsheet link");
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

   addUser(e, sheet);
}

function addUser(e, sheet) {

   var id = e.parameter.id;
   var name = e.parameter.name;
   sheet.appendRow([id, name])
}
```

what i already try :

```
var row = e.range.getRow();
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Timestamp at the time of appending other Details

```
function addUser(e,sheet) {
  
  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var name = e.parameter.name;
  sheet.appendRow([new Date(),id,name])
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it still not working. the google sheet just update the id and name variable

Comment: Try publishing the script to the new version

Comment: Hey there @ZedBaraba, can you please specify what is not working? Are you getting any errors? Moreover, can you please share a sanitized copy of your sheet and perhaps even a desired results screenshot? Cheers!